# Варианты реализации lock-free алгоритма

Tags: c++, c, lock-free

Допустим, есть класс:

```
class LockFree 
{
   LockFree(int num) : n(num) {}
   int next() {n += 1; return n;}
private:
   int n;
};
```

Какие есть стандартные методы организовать lock-free доступ к `n`?
То есть, интересует lock-free (без мьютексов) реализация функции `next()`, которую можно было бы использовать в многопоточной многоядерной системе.

Было бы круто узнать как о возможностях современного стандарта (вероятно это `std::atomic` + варианты `compare_exchange`), так и о самопальных велосипедах, которые можно было бы использовать в plain c.

Comment: @Abyx насколько я понимаю, Стандарт не гарантирует, что тот же `std::atomic<int>` будет реализован без блокировок, а не через какой-нибудь `std::mutex`. Требуется дополнительная проверка через `is_lock_free`

Comment: Классы в plain c... :(

Comment: Выберите один язык. В С++ и C решения будут отличаться.

Comment: @ixSci, а почему нельзя в одном ответе привести примеры для двух языков?

Comment: @Abyx с другой стороны, имхо, возможна ситуация, когда отсутствует поддержка c++11, но возможен lock-free инкремент int'а

Comment: @o2gy допустим, кто-то ответит про си, кто-то про плюсы. Чьё сообщение будет выбрано галочкой как ответ?

Comment: @o2gy, потому что это разные языки. Я C не знаю.

Comment: Вы не можете сделать lock-free-алгоритм без поддержки со стороны стандартной библиотеки. Несинхронизированные многопоточные операции с нативными типами без поддержки наподобие `std::atomic*` согласно стандарту есть UB. Если какой-то трюк работает на одном процессоре, он не будет работать на другом.

Comment: @VladD, ну вроде бы, как минимум, я могу закрыть критическую секцию спинлоком, и затем внутри ковырять нативные типы. Формально, это ведь тоже будет lock-free алгоритм?

Comment: @o2gy: Вы имеете в виду спинлок из стандартной библиотеки, или «ручной»? Потому что вручную вы можете забыть memory barrier и всё остальное, что полагается.

Comment: @VladD, ну, я спрашивал по сути про реализацию неблокирующего доступа - так что более интересно, конечно, было бы посмотреть на "ручной" спинлок. Ну или на понятное обоснование, почему нельзя пользоваться "ручными" спинлоками.

Comment: @o2gy, почему нельзя? IMHO `__atomic_test_and_set` и `__atomic_clear` [отсюда](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) вполне пригодны для "ручного спинлока".

Comment: @o2gy, а этот https://habrahabr.ru/company/ifree/blog/197520/ цикл  статей читали?

Comment: @avp, спасибо! Раньше эти статьи мне не попадались. Интересно, и кстати есть и пример реализации простого spin-лока.

Comment: @avp, но, например, все же не совсем понятны некоторые вещи - например нюансы использования той или иной модели памяти в зависимости от алгоритма. Поэтому больше примеров не помешало бы )

Comment: Про ньюансы в зависимости от алгоритма -- наверное ищите в гугле (может кто-то это уже исследовал и решил поделиться, я не занимался), а немного больше объяснений -- https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync (если еще сами туда не зашли из `__atomic_test_and_set`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой метод:

```
class LockFree 
{
   LockFree(int num) : n(num) {}
   int next() {return ++n;}
private:
   std::atomic<int> n;
};
```

Это покроет все Ваши нужды в 99% случаев.

---

> а если next() будет вида next() { return n + n^2 + n^3; }

Тогда будет так:

```
int next()
{
    int oldN = n;
    while(true)
    {
        int newN = oldN + oldN*oldN + oldN*oldN*oldN;
        if(n.compare_exchange_strong(oldN, newN))
            return newN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37101/discussion-on-answer-by-ixsci---lock-free-).

Answer (score 1):

Больше чтобы не забыть, вариант ответа от ixSci на С:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

int next(atomic_int *n)
{
    int oldN = atomic_load(&n);
    while (1)
    {
        int newN = oldN + oldN*oldN + oldN*oldN*oldN;
        if (atomic_compare_exchange_strong(n, &oldN, newN))
        {
            return newN;
        }
    };
}
```